# How to invoke a job in tsql sql server like listeners do/behave in java

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to implement below design.

Data is coming to source table - *source_tab* and I have 3 procedures to invoke for processing this available data. I am invoking each procedure manually now.

Is there any way to create a job which will be invoked as soon as new data is available in *source_tab* and start processing data by invoking those 3 procedures sequentially. Also, next job cycle should not trigger until current execution gets finished. This should behave in same as Java listeners do. 
I **don't** want to use TRIGGERS.

Comment: You might want to look into Message Queue (MSMQ).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment suggesting MSMQ.  A dirty method, if you don't want to use triggers is to set up a Job on a low interval schedule.

It could check the table, if new data exists then go to first step to execute and flow from there, if not then do nothing.

How you determine what "new" data is that would depend on the data.  Easy enough if you have dateadded column or something similar. If not then you may have to have an additional job step to write the table as it is now into a staging table, then compare this version to the next one on the next run through.

Like I said, not nice but an option.